# How to be able to check if JSON.parse fails or returns a falsey value

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

GOAL:

`const data = JSON.parse(this.description) ? JSON.parse(this.description) : null`

If I run this statement I want to be able to run this on a value that cannot be parsed and return null if it can't. Unfortunately I just get an error that says `Unexpected token at ....`, which I know is because I am passing an un-parsable piece of data in. I want this to be able to return a falsey value so I can set something to null not just break and stop the app.

Attempted:

```
function checkParse(json) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(json);
  } catch (e) {
    return null
  }
}


checkParse(description);
```

This returns an error of `Unexpected token l`

Comment: Use `try/catch`

Comment: @Barmar I am trying the try catch and just getting Unexpected token 1, let me add to an edit of how I am doing this.

Comment: @TaylorAustin: The code you posted does not throw an error: https://jsfiddle.net/243rs4e5/

Comment: Yeah I it's something with the string I am trying to parse.

Answer (score -1):

You could try checking for the variable type before parsing it

```
if(typeof this.description === "string"){data = JSON.parse(this.description}
else{data = null;}
```

Comment: I did try this but the data that I can parse is actually a string. So this would cause all my data to fail, this is a good idea though, I should provide the data that is parsable vs the data that I can't parse.

Comment: This is very wrong. `JSON.parse(...)` expects to be passed a **string** (containing JSON). If you already have an object you don't have to pass it to `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Oh yes also Felix Kling is correct I forgot that it wants a string anyway

Comment: This still won't work. The problem he has is that it's a string, but it's not valid JSON. E.g. `this.description = "foo"`